# Has Essos ever invaded or attacked Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Has any community of Essos ever invaded or attacked Westeros?

As I far as I know, only the Dothraki intended to invade Westeros, because Drogo promised that to Daenerys.

What about the other communities of Essos? Are there none with sailing skills?

Comment: Your premise is false. Armies from Essos have, indeed, invaded Westeros in the past. For example, the Targaryens from Essos became kings after defeating the existing rulers of Westeros.

Comment: @AndresF. If you could expand on that, perhaps mention why they were successful and others weren't ­*coughs fire* that would make a great answer.

Comment: The First men, the Andals, the Rhoynar and the Targaryens all came from Essos!

Comment: @MrLore I don't think it would be an answer, because the premise of the question is incorrect. The Targaryens weren't the only people from Essos who invaded Westeros either, like **curiousdannii** pointed out.

Comment: Being an island matters. How many times has England been invaded in the last two millennia? By the Romans, the Anglo-Saxons, the Danes and the Normans. How about France? Too many to count.

Comment: @PeterShor Westeros is not an island, but a continent. (Though this is confused by the fictional history of Westeros being inspired in England's).

Comment: @curiousdannii your comment is the most correct. Add as an answer!

Comment: @Andres: Both England and Westeros are surrounded by water (unlike Europe, Africa, and Asia). How many times has Australia been invaded?

Comment: I think we're being too quick with the down votes here. Yes, the premise is flawed, but not something that can be fixed. @carlos-heredia if you reword your question to "when, if ever, has Essos invaded Westeros" then it would be an excellent question. And welcome to SciFi.SE!

Comment: @SystemDown Downvotes can and should be used as "no research effort". It's even in the tooltip :) You can also use downvotes to prod the author into improving the question.

Comment: Essos is made-up of *generally* "[Free-Cities](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Free_Cities)", they would usually not want to go to Westeros. Also, many Essosi believe that they are living in a superior land and would probably not want to invade Westeros.

Comment: I take it you mean "Dothraki intended to invade Westeros only because Drogo promised that to Daenerys"?

Answer (score 24):

There were actually several invasions by people from Essos

### Invasion of the First Men - 12,000 years ago

At this time Westeros was settled by the Children of the Forest. But human settlers eventually arrived in Westeros from Essos through a land bridge that connected the two continents at the time called the Arm of Dorne. The humans were later given the name the First Men and arrived with bronze weaponry. First Men and Children of the Forest clashed for a long time, with the humans steadily advancing and cutting of the tress that gave the Children much of their power. The Children used their magic to shatter the Arm of Dorne, but it was too late.

The Children were eventually able to curb the invasion at Moat Cailin, laying down a magical calamity on the area called the Hammer of the Water, that shattered the area into bogs and swamps that separate North from South to this day. The result was a peace accord between the two races, and a friendship that lasted 4000 years that saw the First Men adapting the worship of the Old Gods and other customs.

### Invasion of the Andals - 2,000-6,000 years ago

A second wave of human settlers arrived by sea who called themselves the Andals. They brought iron weaponry and the worship of the Seven. They would eventually invade six of the seven kingdoms, with only the Winter Kings being able to stop them at Moat Cailin.

### Invasion of the Rhoynar - 1,000 years ago

Escaping the violent expansion of the Valyrian Freehold, the Rhoynar arrived in Dorne lead by their warrior queen Nymeria. There, Nymeria married Mors Martell, allying her people with his. The Martell-Rhoynar alliance would eventually conquer all of Dorne.

### Invasion of the Valyrian Freehold - 500 years ago

House Targaryen of Valyria conquered the isle of Dragonstone and built a castle there, making it Valyria's westernmost outpost. A century later, Valyria itself is destroyed in an event called the Doom of Valyria, which was possibly a massive volcanic eruption.

### Invasion of the Targaryens - 300 years ago

A few Valyrian houses headed by House Targaryen escaped the Doom by preemptively migrating to Dragonstone with one dragon, Balerion the Black Dread. There they stayed for 100 years, building up their forces and adding two more dragons to their forces, Vhagar and Meraxes.

From there, Aegon the Conqueror set out to invade the rest of Westeros, successfully uniting the seven kingdoms (with the notable exception of Dorne) under his Iron Throne. The rest is history.

### Spoilers for "A Dance With Dragons"

> **The Invasion of Aegon VI and the Golden Company**
>  Claiming to be Rhaegar Targaryen's son (presumed dead), Aegon VI arrives in Westeros backed by the Golden Company and conquers several cities in the Stormlands and the Stepstones.

Comment: You left out the War of the Ninepenny Kings, when the Blackfyres and the Golden Company captured the Stepstones to use as a base of operations for attacking Westeros.

Comment: @MikeScott I contemplated adding it for a while, but the way I see the Stepstones have never been Westerosi. They've been alternating ownership between so many rulers that it's really hard to categorize them.

Comment: Reasoning from parallels with real history, I suspect the Valyrians were too busy dealing with revolts in their empire and wars with countries to the East to invade Westeros. Nobody would have dared to invade when the Targaryens had dragons. And since then, the nine Free Cities have been too busy fighting amongst themselves.